# Can't Access WCF REST service from any other machine on my local area network

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, wcf-security, self-hosting

None of any similar questions have helped me. I am sure experts here would..

My problem is I am hosting a WCF Rest service and I can only access it locally. Any other computer on the LAN won't be able to access it.

This is how I host my service (this run in a Console application)

```
WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyRestService), new Uri("http://Yaniv-PC:8080/Test"));
```

Here is the Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyRestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        UriTemplate = "/{id}")]
    string GetData(string id);
}
```

And Here is the app.config file (only the serviceModel section)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyRestServiceBehavior" name="ServiceHostApp.MyRestService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceHostApp.IMyRestService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
      <identity>
        <dns value="Yaniv-PC" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyRestServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I open the browser and navigate to: `http://yaniv-pc:8080/test/123`

I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetDataResult>You sent server 123</GetDataResult>
</GetDataResponse>
```

When I access the service from other machine in my LAN i get this error:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
>   listening at `http://yaniv-pc:8080/Test/123` that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A socket operation was attempted
>   to an unreachable network 10.0.0.3:8080

Any ideas?

Comment: Check firewalls.  See if you can browse a flat html file at the server first.  Then, try your service.

Comment: What is the IP of `yaniv-pc`? check if it is `10.0.0.3` or not.

Comment: Are you running this standalone, or are you running it through Visual Studio?

Comment: Im in local network so I am not sure firewall is an issue.. anyway, port is forwarded in firewall. 10.0.0.3 is yaniv-pc. I tried both running visual studio as administrator and run the program from vs, and i also tried to run the console app as standalone application

Comment: @yanivps, It seems to be problem with firewall indeed, if it is able to browse on local machine with same address & port. Please host a simple web application & simply add a html page & browse it from other machine in your LAN. If it is able to browse firewall is not a problem, then, change to default port 80 & try with it.

Comment: Assuming that you are selfhosting your service make sure that you have registered your port using the netsh command for your service as (netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=\everyone). Also try testing it with your PC's firewall disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are self-hosting your service make sure that you have registered your port using the netsh command as below:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=\everyone
```

Also try testing it with your PC's firewall disabled

Answer (score 0):

You should try disable your firewall or try add a rule with port to firewall.